# Actualizar QLineEdit de una ventana secundaria de Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

sigo aprendiendo con esta pagina y con algunos videos, pero no consigo solucionar el fallo...

```
class VentanaI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(VentanaI, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('D:/Sort/python/sort/inspeccion.ui',self)
        self.btSalir.clicked.connect(self.cerrarVInspeccion)
        self.btHacer.clicked.connect(self.procesoInsp)
    def procesoInsp(self):
        if dialogo == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.cbPoblacionMunicipio.isChecked():              
                #self.thread = Proceso1(TotalRegistrosA)
                #self.thread.start()
                self.leSorteo.setText('MUNICIPIOS AGRACIADOS.-')
                #print (self.leSorteo.text())

                self.pbProceso.setMaximum(TotalRegistrosA)
                self.P1 = Proceso1()
                self.P1.start()
                self.P1.any_signal.connect(self.mifuncion)

    def mifuncion(self,contador): # PARA ACTUALIZAR UNA BARRA DE PROGRESO Y UN QLineEdit de la misma VentanaI
        self.pbProceso.setValue (contador)
        self.leNumeros.setText(locale.format_string("%d",contador,grouping=True))


class Proceso1(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self): 
        super(Proceso1,self).__init__()        
        self.is_running = True
    def run(self):
        base = DataBase()
        baseP = DataBaseProvincias()
        rs = base.connection.cursor()
        rsM = baseP.connection.cursor()
        rsUpdate = base.connection.cursor()
        IdMunicipio = 0        
        VInspeccion = VentanaI()
        if VInspeccion.rbPrincipio.isChecked():
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM agraciados WHERE PAIS = "ESPAÑA" ORDER BY id_agraciados;'
        else:
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM agraciados WHERE PAIS = "ESPAÑA" AND id_agraciados >='+configini['AM']+' ORDER BY id_agraciados;'
        print (sql)
        print (VInspeccion.rbPrincipio.isChecked())
        rs.execute(sql)
        reg = rs.fetchall()
        cnt = 0
        for r in reg:
            cnt = cnt + 1
            IdMunicipio = r[0]
            if r[7] != None:
    [b]Fallo ----->[/b]VInspeccion.leLinea.setText('id_agraciados:' + str(r[0]) + ' Fecha: ' + str(r[1]) + ' Sorteo: ' + str(r[2]) + ' Municipio: ' + r[7] + ' Provincia: ' + r[8])
                self.any_signal.emit(cnt)
                query = 'SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE mal = "'+r[7].upper() +'";'
                rsM.execute(query)
                regM = rsM.fetchone()
                if regM != None:
                    print (r[0],' INCORRECTA ' + r[7].upper() + ' CORRECTA: ' + regM[0] + ' ' , cnt)
                #else:
                #    print (r[0] , ' CORRECTA ' + r[7].upper())
            else:
                print (r[0], ' Municipio vacio.-')
```

El problema es que no me actualiza el QLineEdit (leLinea) , mientras que el progressbar (pbProceso) y el otro QLineEdit (leNumeros) si se actualiza desde ese metodo `def mifuncion(self,contador):`

No comprendo como

```
    if VInspeccion.rbPrincipio.isChecked():
```

si funciona, pero `VInspeccion.leLinea.setText(....` que está en la misma ventana, no lo hace.
Como se verá, estoy iniciándome en Python, y hace unos días deje de aprender Java para pasarme a éste, por lo que confundo los terminos pero
comprendo el funcionamiento.

¿ Podéis ayudarme con este fallo?

Gracias y Feliz año nuevo.
4ª ed.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Algo tiene que ver en como defino los Thread, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo bien, ya que si la salida la pongo con prints para la consola me funciona, pero al dirigir la salida al QLineEdit no muestra la información.